# Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'materialSwitch' used with directive '{2}' is non-assignable! (Angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am using Angular Material with Angular 1.3 and have implemented a material switch button that basically has an 'on/off' look that I will use to return a true/false boolean value.

When I click on the div below it returns the following error:

```
Expression 'undefined' in attribute 'materialSwitch' used with directive '{2}' is non-assignable!
```

// my template

```
<div class="user-material-switch" material-switch=""></div>
```

// my directive

```
abcdDirectives.directive('materialSwitch', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        'model': '=',
        'switchDisabled' : '=',
        'switchLabel': '@'
    },
    template: '<div class="material-switch" ng-click="switch()" ng-class="{active: model, disabled: switchDisabled}"><div class="switch-back"></div><div class="switch-front"></div></div>',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs) { 
        scope.switch = function() {
            if (scope.switchDisabled) {
                return;
            }
            scope.model = !!!scope.model;
        }
    }
 }
});
```

Any ideas what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - on the template I hadn't attached the model after the material-switch=""